# List WordPress Custom Menu's active parent level's children as separate menu

Tags: menus

I have a structured Custom Menu:

- parent 1

  - children1_1
  - children1_2
- parent 2

  - children2_1
  - children2_2
- parent 3
- parent 4

  - children4_1

etc.

I want the following: on every page, the parent level items will be shown as main menu.

If a parent level item is active, I want to show the child menu items as a separate list somewhere else in the page.

Is there an "easy" way to achieve this, or do I have to list the menu every time and select the current one with PHP and have headache for this for days? :)

Thanks,
cadeyrn

Comment: JQuery and css were made for this.

Comment: No thank's, I want it to work without js (opera mini for example), and also SEO-proof.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rv-submenus/) do exactly what you want!

Comment: Thanks!

Although I do not want to put it in a widget, this code really does the dirty work.

Comment: How does this plugin solve the original question?

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly simple to execute, using two calls to `wp_list_pages()`, and appropriate variables.

For the primary (i.e. top-level) navigation menu, simply use the `depth` argument, e.g.:

```
wp_list_pages( array(
     // display only top-level hierarchy
     'depth' => 1
) );
```

This will output a menu of all top-hierarchical-level Pages.

For the secondary (i.e. child-page) navigation menu, simply grab the ID of the current Page, and pass it as the `child_of` argument. This requires setting a variable to the `$post->ID` from *inside* the Loop, so that it is available *outside* of the Loop.

e.g. inside the Loop:

```
$parent_page = get_the_ID();
```

And then outside the Loop, for your child-page navigation menu:

```
wp_list_pages( array(
     // display all hierarchical levels
     'depth' => 0,
     // only children of the current Page
     'child_of' => $parent_page
) );
```

The only caveat is that this child-page menu must come *after* the Loop, or else you will need to make an initial pass through the Loop, find the `$post->ID`, and then `rewind_posts()` *before* the Loop.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add some CSS code to your style.css something like `display: inline-block;` (instead of `display: none;`) to `ul.sub-menu` for the `li.current_page_item`?